# How to handle different exceptions in Task?

Tags: javafx, concurrency, java-8

I'm kinda new in JavaFX, and I didn't find any answer to this.

I'm trying to use Task to do some background calculation in a database. The problem is the following : How can I handle exceptions (SQLException, IOException etc ...) in my task.SetOnFailed(e -> ....) function ?

I tried this : e.getSource().getException().getMessage() but I don't think it is the right way to do this.

Comment: Thanks, it works !
Your comment should be the answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can just check the type of the exception:

```
Task<Something> myTask = new Task<Something>() {
    @Override
    public Something call() throws Exception {
        // code...
        return something ;
    }
};

myTask.setOnFailed(e -> {
    Throwable exc = myTask.getException();

    if (exc instanceof SQLException) {
        // ... 
    } else if (exc instanceof IOException) {
       // ...
    } else {
       // ...
    }
});
```

Comment: After testing, you can just modify this line : Exception exc = (Exception) myTask.getException();